# Best practices for Axis2 with Maven

Tags: maven, code-generation, apache-axis

I'm a novice both to Maven and Axis2. My project consists of three modules: client, interface and server. Service is POJO-based. WSDL is being built at the server module. Interface module contains common stuff like service interface and beans.

Should I generate (or copy manually) the WSDL into the interface module? Should I generate client code at the client module? Is the modules structure ok? All I wish to do is make the build process automated but strictly structured.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it doesn't result clear the component that you call 'interface'.
for web service construction there are two main approaches:

- start with the wsdl (that is the contract / or service interface descriptor)
- start with the code (maybe a java interface)

I suggest the first approach because not always you can control both sides of the development. you can use the second one approach to start with a wsdl definition (java2wsdl) or built the wsdl with a tool as altova xmlspy.

Having the wsdl you can use the axis2-maven wsdl2code plugin to develop the WSS (web service server-side). This plugin in the version 2.6.0 only generates the source code of your server, but you need to host this code inside an axis2-war distribution or as an aar component.

Having the wsdl you can use again the axis2-maven wsdl2code plugin to generate the WSC (web service client-side). You can specify in the plugin instruction that you want to generate the test code. You can use mvn generate-sources to generate the client stub, move the generated sources and modify the test.

In both cases, you need to built the initial pom (ath this time I haven't found an official and unified or recommended pom). You can search in google for some pom.xml axis examples (i.e: http://wso2.org/library/90 ).

Below i have some xml that you can use to build the pom (WSC):

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>your_group_id</groupId>
      <artifactId>your_artifact_id</artifactId>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <name>your_artifact_id</name>
      <url>http://your_url</url>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.5</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- axis2/axiom: dependencies -->
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
              <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
              <version>${axis2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
           <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>  
           <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>  
           <version>${axis2.version}</version>  
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
           <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>  
           <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>  
           <version>${axis2.version}</version>  
        </dependency>         
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-codegen</artifactId>
            <version>${axis2.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- axis2-rampart: dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.rampart</groupId>
            <artifactId>rampart-core</artifactId>
            <version>${axis2.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- slf4j: dependencies -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
          <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
          <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
          <!-- 
          <scope>runtime</scope>
          -->
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
          <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- log4j: dependencies -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
          <version>${log4j.version}</version>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- other: dependencies -->
      </dependencies>


      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.6</source>
              <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
              <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>

          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
              <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>${axis2.version}</version>
              <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>wsc_01</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <wsdlFile>${codegen.wsc_01.wsdl-uri}</wsdlFile>
                        <packageName>${codegen.wsc_01.package-name}</packageName>
                        <namespaceToPackages>${codegen.wsc_01.namespace-map}</namespaceToPackages>
                        <outputDirectory>${codegen.wsc.target-dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <databindingName>adb</databindingName>
                        <syncMode>sync</syncMode>
                        <generateServerSide>false</generateServerSide>
                        <generateServicesXml>true</generateServicesXml>
                        <generateTestcase>true</generateTestcase>
                        <language>java</language>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                  <!-- other wsc-generation params -->
              </executions>
          </plugin> 

        </plugins>

      </build>

        <properties>
            <slf4j.version>1.6.3</slf4j.version>  
            <log4j.version>1.2.15</log4j.version>
            <axis2.version>1.6.0</axis2.version>
            <rampart.version>1.6.0</rampart.version>

            <!-- codegen.client.properties -->

            <codegen.wsc_01.wsdl-uri>wsdl_relative_path_or_url</codegen.wsc_01.wsdl-uri>
            <codegen.wsc_01.package-name>your_root_package</codegen.wsc_01.package-name>
            <codegen.wsc_01.namespace-map>http://your_url_namespace=your_java_namespace_mapped</codegen.wsc_01.namespace-map>

            <codegen.wsc.target-dir>target/generated-sources/axis2/wsdl2code</codegen.wsc.target-dir>
        </properties>
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
    </project>
```

Comment: I do control both server and client creation and want to move separate some common beans into separate mode. It seems it isn't very popular solution, so I'm about to get rid of the interface module...